# Dimension of a point in a polynomial ring.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $X \subset \Bbb A^n$ be a nonempty variety. 
 Now suppose $X$ is a point then it easy to see that $\dim_k k[X]  $ is finite. Here
$$k[X]:=\{f \in k[X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n \;| \; f \text{ is a polynomial function} \}$$
This is from Algebraic Geometry (Klaus Hulek), I'm confused why is this easy to see. Any explanation would much much Appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $k[X]=k$... because your varieties are reduced right?

Comment: Thanks that explains it so I just have to show that $k[X]\cong k$ using Isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it does it follow right away that $k[X]=k$ if $k$ is algebraically closed?

Comment: It depends on what you know, how you defined "point" etc... it could be really hard if you don't know some commutative algebra

Comment: By point means literally a point. Sorry for that.

Comment: Well, if $X$ is the point $(a_1, \ldots , a_n)$ of $k^n$, its ideal is the maximal ideal $I=(x_1-a_1, \ldots , x_n-a_n)$ of $k[x_1, \ldots , x_n]$, and so $k[X] = k[x_1, \ldots , x_n]/I =k$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135108/discussion-between-richard-d-and-aitor-iribar-lopez).